# Integrate SDL into GLib mainloop

Tags: sdl, glib, vala

I'm planning a small Vala game project with SDL and I wonder how to integrate SDL properly into the GLib mainloop. The last time I did something with Vala and SDL I used the standard SDL event loop, but honestly, it's a heap of crap and it breaks the whole nice Vala or rather GLib signal system.

I found [an integration for Cogl](https://developer.gnome.org/cogl-2.0-experimental/stable/cogl-2.0-experimental-Main-loop-integration.html#cogl-glib-source-new) and I'm looking for the same thing just with SDL.

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do. If you just want drawing, adding redraw callback to window should be enough (and triggering redraw when something happens that needs to change displayed image). For more regular things there are timers and idle functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLib sources are composed of three callbacks:

- one to check if the source is ready before polling (and avoid a `poll` call)
- one to check if the source is still ready after polling
- one to dispatch the attached callback

You could have a source checking and dispatching events fairly simply.

```vala
public delegate bool SDLSourceFunc (SDL.Event event);

public class SDLSource : Source 
{
    public SDL.Event event;

    public bool prepare (out uint timeout) 
    {
        timeout = 0;
        return true;
    }

    public bool check ()
    {
        return SDL.Event.poll (out event) > 0;
    }

    public bool dispatch (SourceFunc callback) 
    {
        return ((SDLSourceFunc) callback) (event);
    }

    public void add_callback (SDLSourceFunc callback)
    {
        base.add_callback ((SourceFunc) callback);
    }
}
```

Then, you would loop with `Source.CONTINUE`:

```vala
var source = new SDLSource ();

source.add_callback ((event) => {
    // handle event here
    return Source.CONTINUE;
});

source.attach (MainContext.@default ());
```

This is very basic: your source could filter specific events with a `SDL.EventMask` and `SDL.peep`. It's also more efficient to dispatch multiple events for a single source and attach related file descriptors.

If you use some async code, you can wakeup the coroutine directly from a `Source` dispatch:

```vala
public async void next_event_async () 
{
    var source = new SDLSource ();
    source.attach (MainContext.@default ());
    source.add_callback (next_event_async.callback);
    yield;
    return source.event;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly SDL makes this very difficult. Ideally the SDL API would provide a file descriptor to listen on that would be signalled whenever an event is available so that you could add it to the glib main loop, but it doesn't have this.

Although it's less than ideal, I think the simplest and most portable approach would just be to install a timer to check for SDL events regularly. You could do this with [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) to wake up the main loop at regular intervals and then just call SDL_PollEvent in the callback.

This is similar to the [answer given by arteymix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305327/4046512), except that beware that the approach given there will effectively cause a busy wait (the prepare function returns a zero timeout if no events are available) so it will end up always using 100% CPU.

Clutter used to have an [SDL backend](https://git.gnome.org/browse/clutter/tree/clutter/sdl/clutter-event-sdl.c?id=ae188d203c63d680dc58ba1e19f333719a6916d4#n131) which you can still see in the Git history. It basically takes this approach of waking up the main loop at regular intervals except that it creates a custom source instead of using g_timeout_add.

Considering that you are writing a game, if you are expecting to continuously redraw anyway and have the process regularly block in SDL_GL_SwapWindow, it might make more sense to just install an idle handler with [g_idle_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) and then do all of your SDL stuff in the callback. You can check events at that start of the idle callback and then call SDL_GL_SwapWindow at the end which blocks waiting for the redraw to complete anyway meaning it won't take up 100% CPU.